# Is there a way to create a pop-up window with text in Vaadin 14 that disallows copying the text?

Tags: javascript, java, user-interface, web, vaadin

we are using Vaadin 14 and attempting to create a pop-up Window of some sort, that contains a TextArea with text in it.

We would like to know how to prevent this text from being copied, both by Ctrl+C, and by disabling right click.

We are aware that this is not perfect protection, and that a savvy user can view the source of the page to retrieve the content.

Disabling the TextArea has the intended effect of preventing copying and pasting of the text, but it also disallows scrolling in case the text is larger than the TextArea itself.

I tried to disable the TextArea itself, which does seem to prevent copying content from TextArea, but it also disables the scrollbars.

Is there a way to do this without sacrificing scrollbars for the sake of preventing copying / right click menu on a TextArea?

Thank you.

Comment: Prevent the selection instead of trying to prevent copying?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You could make the TextArea very high and instead make its container element scrollable (either use a Scroller component or CSS overflow styles)?

Comment: An approach to suppress copying text (even with development tools in the browser) is to print that text into an image and show that image.

Comment: Suppressing right click or Ctrl+C could be done in JavaScript with an event listener that stops propagation: `event.stopPropagation();`